# Group by weekofyear MySQL for the end of the year

Tags: mysql, sql

I need stats on orders, week by week, so I have done this:

```
SELECT YEAR(orders.date), WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date), COUNT(*)
FROM orders 
GROUP BY YEAR(orders.date), WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date)
```

It worked for one year, but just now (new year) it does not count the last days of 53rd week (jan 1st, 2nd, 3rd). How can I update my Query in order to have the full last week (from Monday `2015-12-28` to Sunday `2016-01-03`)?

Comment: Um, see WEEK() maybe?

Comment: @Strawberry OK thanks but it will be the same problem with WEEK(date,3) : WEEKOFYEAR is just an alias of WEEK(date,3). Did I miss something?

Comment: Use `YEARWEEK(orders.date,3)` to get the ISO weeks

Comment: What if you take out the `YEAR(orders.date)` from your query, so just `SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date), COUNT(*) FROM orders GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date);`? Because `WEEKOFYEAR` does seem to give 53 for both Dec 31 and Jan 1.

Comment: @pjd: `YEARWEEK(orders.date,3)` instead of `YEAR(orders.date), WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date)`

Comment: @dnoeth Yeah, that is better since it gives `201553` instead of just `53`, which will be important as the years go by. I already upvoted you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch to [`YEARWEEK(orders.date,3)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) to get the ISO weeks as a single column. Using `WEEK(orders.date,3)` (which is exactly the same as `WEEKOFYEAR`) will return the correct week number, but `YEAR(orders.date)` will return either 2015 or 2016, splitting the week into four days in 2015 and and three days in 2016.

Comment: That's the best answer, thanks. `WEEK` end up with two entries for one same week.

Answer (score 1):

As Strawberry mentioned in the comments you're looking for the `WEEK` function. I just checked the documentation at the MySQL website.

**Week(date [,mode])**

> This function returns the week number for date. The two-argument form of WEEK() enables you to specify whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday and whether the return value should be in the range from 0 to 53 or from 1 to 53. If the mode argument is omitted, the value of the default_week_format system variable is used

Here's an example

```
SELECT WEEK('2008-12-31',1);
=> 53
```

It should also be noted that this is not the same as the `WEEKOFYEAR` function.

> Returns the calendar week of the date as a number in the range from **1 to 53**. WEEKOFYEAR() is a compatibility function that is equivalent to **WEEK(date,3)**.

We can see that the value of the mode parameter here is 3. Here is the table that shows the values for the modes

```
Mode First day of week  Range   Week 1 is the first week
0    Sunday             0-53    With a Sunday in this year
1    Monday             0-53    With 4 or more days this year
2    Sunday             1-53    With a Sunday in this year
3    Monday             1-53    With 4 or more days this year
4    Sunday             0-53    With a Sunday in this year
5    Monday             0-53    With 4 or more days this year
6    Sunday             1-53    With a Sunday in this year
7    Monday             1-53    With 4 or more days this year
```

Source

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: Checking the documentation? That's kind of cheating ;-)

Comment: But the problem with this answer is that `2015-12-31` and `2016-01-01` end up in different weeks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you want calculate total orders for one week only once not twice for various years.

I've written SQL query for SQL Server, but I think you can easy rewrite it on mysql.

```
DECLARE @test_table TABLE(created_date DATETIME, VALUE INT)

INSERT INTO @test_table
SELECT N'20151231', 10
UNION ALL
SELECT N'20151228', 20
UNION ALL
SELECT N'20160101', 40
UNION ALL
SELECT N'20160104', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT N'20160107', 2

SELECT first_day_week_number,
       SUM(value) AS total 
FROM
    (SELECT *,
           DATEPART(ww, 
                    DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, created_date)+2, created_date)) AS first_day_week_number
    FROM @test_table ) AS T
GROUP BY first_day_week_number
```

To avoid problems with years you could calculate first week day of order date and then get week number from it.